# MongoDB aggregation including missing documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents stored in a MongoDB similar to the following:

```js
{
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Blogs",
    "results":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "mark": "78" },
            { "id": "5002", "mark": "105" },
            { "id": "5005", "mark": "97" },
        ]
}
```

There are many entries similar to the above. The problem I have is that some "results" fields are missing entirely so some entries look like below:

```js
{
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Blogs"
}
```

I'm trying to aggregate this to return the "name", "last_name" and an average "mark". I was getting on well with the below code:

```js
db.sites.aggregate( 
 { $project : { name : "$name", last_name : "$last_name", results : "$results" } },
 { $unwind: "$results" },
 { $group : { 
    _id : "$_id", 
    average_mark : { $avg : "$results.mark" }, 
    name : { $last : "$name" },
    last_name : { $last : "$last_name" },
 }
)
```

However, it does not return an entry where there is no "results" array.

Does anyone have any idea how to return the missing "results" entries and set the average to zero?

Cheers,

James.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the aggregation framework encounters an "empty" array, the result of an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) effectively removes the document from the pipeline, as it is considered that there would be no results. Also if the array is not present at all, then an error would be produced as the operator would try to access an element that does not exist.

For this reason, where you do not wish to explicitly "filter" those documents from your aggregation results, the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator exists. It tests for the presence of a field an either returns that field or the alternate supplied argument.

```js
db.sites.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "name": 1, 
        "last_name": 1,
        "results" : { 
            "$ifNull": [ "$results", [{ "mark": 0 }] ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$results" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id" : "$_id", 
        "average_mark": { "$avg": "$results.mark" }, 
        "name": { "$last": "$name" },
        "last_name": { "$last": "$last_name" },
    }}
])
```

Similar results can be achieved with the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator when you truly have an "empty" array, and even in combination:

```js
    "results": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            {"$eq": [ "$results", [] ] },
            [{ "mark": 0 }],
            { "$ifNull": [ "$results", [{ "mark": 0 }] ] }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Neil. This is perfect, and the explanation was great. I can also apply this to another situation where we don't always have contact information. Thanks again.